Running a large javascript file from within Python and applying a second javascript 'fetch ... then' to the original code
Currently I can retrieve a HMAC-Secret and AES-key with a Python script by running an html fragment in a headless browser, parsing the browser page returned and obtaining said secret and key.
The html fragment is this:
<head>
    <script src="https://player.akamaized.net/html5player/core/html5-c5-player.js"></script>
    <script>
        fetch("https://player.akamaized.net/html5player/core/html5-c5-player.js")
            .then((r) => r.text())
            .then((b) => {
                const dfnm = /\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x6f\x66\x20([a-z0-9]+)\[(\d+)\]\.([a-z0-9]+)\x20\x3d\x3d\x3d\x20\x27\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x27/gi.exec(b);
                const krm = /\x27\\x68\x27:[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\((\d+)\),'\\x61':[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\((\d+)\)/gi.exec(b);
                document.write(JSON.stringify({ HMAC_SECRET: window[dfnm[1]][dfnm[2]][dfnm[3]](krm[1]), AES_KEY: window[dfnm[1]][dfnm[2]][dfnm[3]](krm[2]) }));
            });
    </script>
</head>

The whole operation takes over 7 seconds to run because of the time overhead of starting a headless browser. I would like to execute the JavaScript from within Python code using a module such as js2py.
I am now confused as to how to apply the 'fetch ... then' construct to the JavaScript downloaded.
I have this Python so far:-
import requests
import js2py

js2 = b""".then((r) => r.text())
            .then((b) => {
                const dfnm = /\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x6f\x66\x20([a-z0-9]+)\[(\d+)\]\.([a-z0-9]+)\x20\x3d\x3d\x3d\x20\x27\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x27/gi.exec(b);
                const krm = /\x27\\x68\x27:[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\((\d+)\),'\\x61':[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\((\d+)\)/gi.exec(b);
                document.write(JSON.stringify({ HMAC_SECRET: window[dfnm[1]][dfnm[2]][dfnm[3]](krm[1]), AES_KEY: window[dfnm[1]][dfnm[2]][dfnm[3]](krm[2]) }));
            });"""

def get_hmac_aes_keys():
    # Fetch HTML content
    response = requests.get('https://player.akamaized.net/html5player/core/html5-c5-player.js')
    if response.status_code == 200:
        js = response.text
        
        # Execute JavaScript code using js2py
        context = js2py.EvalJs()
        context.execute(js + js2)


        
get_hmac_aes_keys()

But that produces a warning - SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
And an error - KeyError: 3  from js2py (Is js2py up to managing this level of complexity?)
So here I am stuck...
[EDIT 15 days later]
... some while later....
The issue largely devolved down to the javascript refusing to run via python as it had terms like 'self', referring to a non-existing browser document.
A solution was eventually found that allows python to call nodejs to run a modified javascript in simulated_browser.
The code is here:
import subprocess
import json
import os

js_code = """
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const fs = require("fs");

async function simulateBrowser() {
    const fetch = await import('node-fetch').then(mod => mod.default);

    const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body></body>`, {
        url: "https://player.akamaized.net/",
        resources: "usable",
        runScripts: "dangerously"
    });
    const window = dom.window;

    window.fetch = fetch;

    try {
        const response = await window.fetch("https://player.akamaized.net/html5player/core/html5-c5-player.js");
        const jsCode = await response.text();
        const scriptElement = window.document.createElement("script");
        scriptElement.textContent = jsCode;
        window.document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);

        const inlineScript = `
            fetch('https://player.akamaized.net/html5player/core/html5-c5-player.js')
                .then((r) => r.text())
                .then((b) => {
                    const dfnm = /\\\\x72\\\\x65\\\\x74\\\\x75\\\\x72\\\\x6e\\\\x20\\\\x74\\\\x79\\\\x70\\\\x65\\\\x6f\\\\x66\\\\x20([a-z0-9]+)\\\\[(\\\\d+)\\\\]\\\\.([a-z0-9]+)\\\\x20\\\\x3d\\\\x3d\\\\x3d\\\\x20\\\\x27\\\\x66\\\\x75\\\\x6e\\\\x63\\\\x74\\\\x69\\\\x6f\\\\x6e\\\\x27/gi.exec(b);
                    const krm = /\\\\x27\\\\\\\\x68\\\\x27:[a-z0-9]+\\\\.[a-z0-9]+\\\\((\\\\d+)\\\\),'\\\\\\\\x61':[a-z0-9]+\\\\.[a-z0-9]+\\\\((\\\\d+)\\\\)/gi.exec(b);
                    if (!dfnm || !krm) {
                        window.simulationResult = { error: 'Regex did not match any content', dfnm, krm };
                        return;
                    }
                    window.simulationResult = {
                        HMAC_SECRET: window[dfnm[1]][dfnm[2]][dfnm[3]](krm[1]),
                        AES_KEY: window[dfnm[1]][dfnm[2]][dfnm[3]](krm[2]),
                    };
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    window.simulationResult = { error: err.message };
                });
        `;
        const inlineScriptElement = window.document.createElement("script");
        inlineScriptElement.textContent = inlineScript;
        window.document.body.appendChild(inlineScriptElement);

        // Wait for the fetch and processing to complete
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

        // Write the result to a file
        if (window.simulationResult) {
            fs.writeFileSync("output.json", JSON.stringify(window.simulationResult));
        } else {
            fs.writeFileSync("output.json", JSON.stringify({ error: 'Unknown error' }));
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error in simulateBrowser:', err);
        fs.writeFileSync("output.json", JSON.stringify({ error: err.message }));
    }
}

simulateBrowser().catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error in simulateBrowser:', err);
    fs.writeFileSync("output.json", JSON.stringify({ error: err.message }));
});
"""

with open("simulate_browser.js", "w") as f:
    f.write(js_code)

result = subprocess.run(["node", "simulate_browser.js"], capture_output=True, text=True)

if result.returncode != 0:
    print("Error executing JavaScript file")
    print(result.stderr)
    exit()

if not os.path.exists("output.json"):
    print("output.json file was not created")
    print("Node.js output:", result.stdout)
    exit()

with open("output.json", "r") as f:
    output = json.load(f)

if "error" in output:
    print("Error in JavaScript execution:", output["error"])
else:
    print(output)



js + js2 is not valid JavaScript. What do you expect to happen and why? I think, js2 should only be the code block in the second then.

If I load the head html into a browser the browser returns (today - next week something else)
HMAC_SECRET = "P5ElvzfPJfdhXu/8gT8DUw=="
AES_KEY = "8Q/KTkVOLCV7m+cjvkm1Vg=="
So clearly the javascript is fine - it is my implementation of python trying to get JavasScript to run that is in errror

No, your implementation is clearly not fine. js in the Python code contains the same string as b in the JavaScript code. Log it to compare. Now, it should be obvious, that you have to remove the .then from js2. response.text doesn't return a promise.

I think we may be at cross purposes slightly. The javascript runs in broswer fine.  Full stop.

Altered
        
        # Execute JavaScript code using pythonmonkey
        context = pm.eval(js)
        context.execute(js2)


ReferenceError: self is not defined
Stack Trace:
  @evaluate:1:1570819
  r6@evaluate:1:14976
  @evaluate:1:1485912
  r6@evaluate:1:14976
  @evaluate:1:16391
  @evaluate:1:16420```

Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Add additional details to your question. I don't what else is unclear. b contains the same string as js. You have to implement the logic from the then block in Python.
